# Error function for AJAX invoked (no transport) but shouldn't be accordnig to documentation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

According to [jQuery DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), the *error* function is not called for cross-domain requests. I'm making such a request but still get the *error* function invoked (with "No Transport" as the error message).

Can't explain why... Note - I'm not asking what the error means. I know that already. I'm curious why the function is invoked despite the fact that the documentation states that it won't be for cross-domain requests.

> Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests. This is an Ajax Event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-domain script and JSONP requests are not implemented using `XMLHttpRequest` at all, but using dynamically generated `<script>` tags which load and evaluate the response as actual Javascript. This means that lots of the error-handling mechanisms of `XMLHttpRequest` are not available, and most errors will not trigger the `error` handler — simply because those errors will not be caught by jQuery. This is what the note in the documentation means.

The "No Transport" error on the other hand occurs *before* the request is even started, and the likely reason is that your requests' `dataType` is neither `'jsonp'` nor `'script'`, which are the supported response data types for cross-domain requests.

Comment: So you mean that the note warns that **not all** errors will be reliably reported and fired upon **but some** will? The wording in the API is a bit unfortunate, in such case.